# Repositioning for minimap display

Tags: geometry

I'm doing some game development and have the following problem:

I've got a mini map that I draw on, the image is $300\times 300$ in size and I'm displaying the player and enemies that are within a range of ($500$) of the player.

They have map coordinates that can be anything from $(-1000, -1000)$ to $(1000, 1000)$, I've set the player to the center $(150, 150)$ and then I want reposition enemies in my list of enemies (has a position) within the mini map.

What I'm having some problems wrapping my head around how to do display enemies. The "factor" is $6,666$ $(1000/150)$, can I just divide enemy position by this factor? $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yeah, that should work, but since you'll obtain floating point numbers that way, you might want to use a better technique. For instance euclidean division if you want to avoid using floating point numbers altogether, or at the very least use a floor/ceiling function to obtain integers.

Comment: You might want to ask questions of this sort on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following approach: take your X coordinate, multiply it by $3$ and then perform a [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Division_algorithm) by $10$. (Since $\frac{3}{10}=\frac{150}{500}$ and since you only want enemies within range $500$.) Apply the same procedure to the Y coordinate.

The result will be the transformed coordinates for the minimap.